# Path induction implied

Tags: types, agda

This is a follow-up question to [Getting path induction to work in Agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634363/getting-path-induction-to-work-in-agda)

I wonder when that construct may be more expressive. It seems to me we can always express the same like so:

```
f : forall {A} -> {x y : A} -> x == y -> "some type"
f refl = instance of "some type" for p == refl
```

Here Agda will do path induction given the example which is the same as `c : (x : A) -> C refl` from that question:

```
pathInd : forall {A} -> (C : {x y : A} -> x == y -> Set)
                     -> (c : (x : A) -> C refl)
                     -> {x y : A} -> (p : x == y) -> C p
```

It seems this function is isomorphic to:

```
f' : forall {A} -> {x y : A} -> x == y -> "some type"
f' = pathInd (\p -> "some type") (\x -> f {x} refl)
```

Are these two ways (`f` vs `pathInd`) identical in power?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://homotopytypetheory.org/2011/04/10/just-kidding-understanding-identity-elimination-in-homotopy-type-theory/

Comment: @user3237465 yes, i am reading through that. Yet my question is about Agda doing path induction for `f`. I don't see the use for `pathInd`, expressed as a function just like in HoTT, unless it is in some way more general than `f`. In other words, since to use `pathInd` one needs to replicate the same thing one needs to do to define `f`, I don't see if there is anything practical to be gained by introducing `pathInd`, except for exercise, which of course is a merit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pathInd` is just a dependent eliminator. Here is an isomorphic definition:

```
  J : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {x y : A}
    -> (C : {x y : A} {p : x ≡ y} -> Set β)
    -> ({x : A} -> C {x} {x})
    -> (p : x ≡ y) -> C {p = p}
  J _ b refl = b
```

Having this, you can define various functions on `_≡_` without pattern-matching, for example:

```
  sym : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {x y : A}
      -> x ≡ y
      -> y ≡ x
  sym = J (_ ≡ _) refl

  trans : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {x y z : A}
        -> x ≡ y
        -> y ≡ z -> x ≡ z
  trans = J (_ ≡ _ -> _ ≡ _) id

  cong : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : Set β} {x y : A}
       -> (f : A -> B) 
       -> x ≡ y
       -> f x ≡ f y
  cong f = J (f _ ≡ f _) refl

  subst : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {x y : A}
        -> (C : A -> Set β)
        -> x ≡ y
        -> C x -> C y
  subst C = J (C _ -> C _) id
```

But you can't prove uniqueness of identity proofs from `J` as described at [1]:

```
  uip : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {x y : A} -> (p q : x ≡ y) -> p ≡ q
  uip refl refl = refl
```

So you can express more with Agda's pattern-matching, than with just a dependent eliminator for `_≡_`. But you can use the `--without-K` option:

```
{-# OPTIONS --without-K #-}

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality  

uip : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {x y : A} -> (p q : x ≡ y) -> p ≡ q
uip refl refl = refl
```

`uip` doesn't typecheck now, causing this error:

```
Cannot eliminate reflexive equation x = x of type A because K has
been disabled.
when checking that the pattern refl has type x ≡ x
```

[1] http://homotopytypetheory.org/2011/04/10/just-kidding-understanding-identity-elimination-in-homotopy-type-theory/

Answer (score 6):

To provide a short answer: you're right, Agda's pattern matching implies the existence of a path-induction primitive.  In fact, it has been shown that in a type theory with universes, dependent pattern matching is equivalent to the existence of induction primitives for inductive types and the so-called K axiom:

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11780274_27

More recently, it has been shown that (the latest implementation of) Agda's --without-K option restricts pattern matching such that it is only equivalent with the existence of induction primitives for inductive types:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2628136.2628139

Full disclosure: I'm a co-author of the latter work.