# Implementation of Transitivity of Equality in Agda (HoTT)

Tags: agda, topology, type-theory

After hours of trying different versions of it, I give up. I just want to typecheck a proof of the transitivity of equality as stated in the HoTT-Book. I'm new to Agda so it might be just a small flaw or perhaps a bigger one... dont know. I consulted different libs for HoTT in Agda, but the ones I found had (in my eyes) rather complex solutions.

```
trans : ∀ {ℓ} (A : Type ℓ) (x y : A)
        → (x == y) → (z : A) → (y == z) → (x == z) 
trans A x y = pathInd (λ p → (z : A) → (y == z) → (x == z)) 
                (λ x → pathInd (λ x → (z : A) → (x == z) → (x == z))) (λ x → refl x))
```

Its based on the following implementation of path induction.

```
pathInd : ∀ {m n} {A : Type m} (P : {x y : A} → (x == y) → Type n) →
        (∀ x → P (refl x)) → ∀ {x y} (p : (x == y)) → P p
pathInd P r (refl x) = r _
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/vituscze/HoTT-lectures/blob/master/src/PathOperations.agda#L13) help? (J is defined [here](https://github.com/vituscze/HoTT-lectures/blob/master/src/Types.agda#L102)).

Comment: Another implementation of `trans` via `J` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26656674/3237465).

Comment: That other implementation did help. Thanks.